# How to describe work experience from before the existance of the industry term?

Tags: software-industry, resume, work-experience

Today I came across the term "Robotic Process Automation" (sorry if this is old news).

I realize this is something I've actually been doing for the last 8 years, although the term itself seems like it started only 4 years ago.

How would I present this type of work history accurately?  I obviously did not use any RPA tools 8 years ago since they didn't exist, but I was right at home with the CE edition of UiPath.

Comment: How would you have described it yesterday?

Comment: Not an issue- simply use today's terms.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is actually VERY common in technology.

My entire career has been strongly linked to ETL, but I never heard "ETL" as an industry term until a few years ago.

The fact of the matter is that you've simply been doing the work longer than they've had a name in it.  You can legitimately call yourself a pioneer in "Robotic Process Automation" and note that you were doing the work even before the current tools existed.

I know something like that would get my interest, and on the interview, I'd want to know all about it.

To represent it on your resume, put the entire time you've been doing the work under a heading, then date the inclusion of tools....

EXAMPLE

Pioneer in automated widget manufacturing,   2011-present

2012 - incorporated "autowidget" into our toolset, quickly achieved mastery with that tool.

2013 - adopted "widgetmaster" as shop standard tool...

2014- pres  - "Widgetmaster professional suite became shop standard, trained, mastered and trained others.

Comment: I usually add my ETL knowledge under just a "data" section and rather explain in person the full detail

Answer (score 2):

As @WendyG said "How would you have described it yesterday?"

```
  2011 - Present 
       {yesterday's definition} (Now called *Robotic Process Automation*)
```

I had the same problem years ago with Ajax (was called Atlas or something, and my usage predated even that).